# MVC Route Contraint not working (odd)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following route, with a constraint set up to only allow an id that starts with "CAR":

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "Car Detail",
        "AR/Car/{id}",
        new { controller = "Car", action = "Detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { id = @"^CAR" },
        namespaces: new[] { "CarSubmission.Areas.AR.Controllers" }
    );
```

And I am attempting to use this URL:

www.myapp.com/CarSubmission/AR/Car/CAR223126

When hitting this url in the browser, however, the route doesn't engage.  Any ideas?

Is this regular expression (i.e. "^CAR") wrong for c#?  I need the regular expression to look for "CAR" followed by any number of numeral characters after it.

Comment: Is this route above the "default" one that appears in the route config? If it does not, try moving your route so that it is listed before the "default" route.

Comment: In addition to what others have mentioned, is CarSubmission the root of your site?  If not, your template won't match either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `^` (or `$`) for segment constraints.

Despite of that, your regular expression is wrong, since you are not expecting any character **after** `"CAR"`.

You should have something like this:

```
CAR\d+
```

Which would match `CAR` followed by **one or more** numbers.

Or:

```
CAR\d{6}
```

Which would match `CAR` followed by **exactly 6** digits.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't "^CAR" only match the string "CAR"?  Try @"^CAR\d+"

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is wrong. What you have is looking for just the string `CAR`. You need to tell it to match digits on the end. Try this:

```
^CAR\d*
```

Which says "match a string starting with `CAR` and any number of digits afterwards."